# Does making an object reference null, releases a memory occupied by that object

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Does making an object reference `null`, releases a memory occupied by that object.
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Billing_productModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        list.add(new BillingProductModel());
    }
    System.out.println("Size of List : "+list.size());
    list = null;
    while(true);
}
```

Here I have created an `Arraylist` and added 100 new objects to it. 
If I make object reference (list) `null`, does Garbage Collecter clears a memory allocated to list.

Comment: It doesn't release memory immediately because the object still exists after the variable pointing to it stops doing so. Memory release will only take place when the object is garbage-collected. And yes, if `list` was the only variable pointing to it, that array list instance is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Yes. It'd release when gc would run.

Comment: @ShanuGupta: how can you say that as you have no idea if that same object is referred to elsewhere in the program. GC is never as simple as just setting a reference variable to null.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was talking about the program in question. It has anonymous objects.